# Show the price in a textbox after selecting the id from a selected menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have two selected menu the 1st one we chose the type so the next will filter the mysql database to show the depertments numbers,  and i need to show the depertment price in a textfiled after i select the depertment number from the second selectedmenu.

1st selected menu

```
<select name="gender" id="gender" class="update">
      <option value="">Select one</option>
      <?php if (!empty($list)) { ?>
      <?php foreach($list as $row) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['name']; ?> 
        <?php }   ?>
      </option>
      <?php } ?>
  </select>
```

2nd selected menu

```
<select name="category" 
        disabled="disabled" class="update" id="category" onChange="precio()" onClick="show()" >
       <option value="">----</option>
  </select>
```

this is how i get the value for the 2nd selected value

update.php

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['value'])) {

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $value = $_GET['value'];


    try {

        $objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name', 'root', '1234');
        $objDb->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

        $sql = "SELECT * 
                FROM  `depertamientos` 
                WHERE `master` = ?";
        $statement = $objDb->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute(array($value));
        $list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (!empty($list)) {

            $out = array('<option value="">Select one</option>');

            foreach($list as $row) {
                if ($row['visible'] == 0) { 
                    $out[] = '<option value="'.$row['name'].'" id="'.$row['precio'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
                }
            }
            echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'list' => implode('', $out)));

        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
    }

} else {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
}
```

core.js

```
var formObject = {
    run : function(obj) {
        if (obj.val() === '') {
            obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            var id = obj.attr('id');
            var v = obj.val();
            jQuery.getJSON('mod/update.php', { id : id, value : v}, function(data) {
                if (!data.error) {
                    obj.next('.update').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled');
                } else {
                    obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
$(function() {

    $('.update').live('change', function() {
        formObject.run($(this));
    });

});

js function 

>  <script src="javascripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


            function show() {
                var select = document.getElementById('category');
                var input = document.getElementById('ds');
                var change = document.getElementById('dpto');
                var deptprecio = document.getElementById('11');

                        select.onchange = function() {
                                input.value = select.value;
                                deptprecio.value = "I don't know what to do here ???? ";
                                change.value = select.value;

                        }
            }

    </script>
```

my data base :

```
id    master        name      visible    precio 
-------------------------------------------------

1        0        Type a         0         0       

2        0        type b         0         0

3        1         101           1        20000

4        1         201           1        10000

5        2         103           1        30000
```

Comment: and what is the question ?

Comment: why generate `HTML`, `json_encode` it and decode it ? it could be better if your service just return data (a json object for example) and you generate your `HTML` in `javascript`. Also you load jquery so why not using it for all your javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why putting the price as the id of your `options` tag ? Why not putting it in the value propertie  as in @WebDevRon example?

```
$out[] = '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
```

remove javascript event in your your HTML tag:

```
<select name="category" 
        disabled="disabled" class="update" id="category" >
       <option value="">----</option>
</select>
```

and if i understand your request you could just replace your `javascript` function "show" by something like this:

```
$("#category").change(function () {
    var price = $(this).val();
    $('#price-input').val(price); // where "price-input" is the id of your input.
});
```

Edit:

use data-attibute to store the price:

```
   $out[] = '<option value="'.$row['name'].'"  data-price="'.$row['precio'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

    $('.update').live('change', function() {
        formObject.run($(this));
    });


    $("#category").change(function () {
        var dept_number = $(this).val();
        var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
        $('#dept-input').val(dept_number);
        $('#price-input').val(price);
    });

});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4qBWs/2/)

Comment: the problem that i had anothere textfield that show the depertmant number that i get it from the 2nd selected list and i am using the value for that so if i change  the value to price it wont work !!!!!!

Comment: so you have to store 2 values for each `option`, one solution is to use data-attributes. I edited my post.

Comment: i don't get exactly where i have to put the js code can you help me with that

Comment: just remove the code of the function "show()" and you can put the js part with the rest of your js code. Edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your complete solution - [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webdevron/4qBWs/)**

```
var $select2 = $('#select2');
var $text = $('#price');

$("#select1").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    if ($select2.data('options') == undefined) {
        $select2.data('options', $select2.find('option').clone());
    }
    var options = $select2.data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
    $select2.html(options);

    $text.val(id);
});
```

Comment: did you see the demo..?

Comment: your demo is not exactly what he need.

Comment: If you need a database action then you should try json_encode

Comment: the demo is not what i need i need to know how to get the price field frommy database and then show it in the textbox so when i submit the form i addthe price to the buying table